# Spring Batch - How to make two queries or pass two objects to the Processor or writer?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I am developing ***Spring Boot Spring Batch*** code. Reading data from the `Oracle DB` and loading all the data into the `MongoDB (NOSQL DB)`. Modelling of `MongoDB` is developed as de-normalized way as per the standard way of implementing mongo relations/modelling.

I've `TableA` and `TableB` table and Join Table `TableAB` between them which is 3rd Table. When I read `TableA` Table via `JdbcCursorItemReader<TableA>` that time for each **PK Id** of `TableA` I need to Query to `SubDivision` Table to get all the `SubDivision` for the `TableA`'s PK and populate SubDivision Data set it into model of TableA. TableA model has list Of `SubDivisions`.

The only way I see making the query from `TableAProcessor` and set data into the model of `TableA`, its easy to implement, but issue is that its making 100K calls to DB from TableAProcess if I've ***100K TableA records***.

How can I achieve this and set the `SubDivision` data to the model of `TableA` from either using Tasklet or any other way?

How to avoid calling so many query from Processor ?

I cant make a single query due to some limitations hence I need to query one more query to DB to get SubDivision Data.

```
@Slf4j
public class TableAProcessor implements ItemProcessor<TableA, TableA>{

    @Autowired
    private TableADao tableADao;

    @Override
    public TableA process(TableA tableA) throws Exception {
        log.debug("TableA DETAILS : "+tableA);
        List<SubDivision> subDivisions = tableADao.getSubDivision(tableA.getPKId());
        tableA.setSubDivisions(subDivisions);
        return tableA;
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class TableA {
    @Transient
    private Integer Id;
    @Field
    private String mongoId;
    ........
    .......
    @Field
    private List<SubDivision> subDivisions;
}
```

TableABatchConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class TableABatchConfig {

    private static final String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLEA";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="oracleDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<TableA> TableAReader() throws Exception {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<TableA> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<TableA>();
        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setSql(sql);

        reader.setRowMapper(new TableARowMapper());
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<TableA, TableA> TableAProcessor() {
        return new TableAProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public TableAWriter TableAWriter() {
        return new TableAWriter();
    }
}
```

TableAJob.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class TableAJob {
    @Value( "${spring.chunk.size}")
    private String chunkSize;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcCursorItemReader<TableA> TableAReader;

    @Autowired
    private ItemProcessor<TableA, TableA> TableAProcessor;

    @Autowired
    private TableAWriter TableAWriter;

    @Bean
    public TableAStepExecuListner TableAStepExecuListner() {
        return new TableAStepExecuListner();
    }

    @Bean("readTableAJob")
    @Primary
    public Job readTableAJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("readTableAJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(TableAStepOne())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step TableAStepOne() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("TableAStepOne")
                .<TableA, TableA>chunk(Integer.parseInt(chunkSize))
                .reader(TableAReader)
                .processor(TableAProcessor)
                .writer(TableAWriter)
                .listener(TableAStepExecuListner())
                .build();
    }
}
```

dao

```
@Service
public class TableADao {

    private static final String SQL = "COMPLEX JOIN QUERY";

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<SubDivision> getSubDivision(Integer pkId){
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL,new Object[] { pkId });

        List<SubDivision> divisions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map<String, Object> row : results) {
            divisions.add(SubDivision.builder().subDivisionCd((String)row.get("SUBDIVISION_CD"))
                    ......
                    .........
                    .........
                    ......
                    .build());
        }
        return divisions;
    }
}
```

TableAWriter.java

```
public class TableAWriter implements ItemWriter<TableA>{
    @Autowired
    private TableARepository TableARepository;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends TableA> items) throws Exception {
        TableARepository.saveAll(items);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a common pattern known as the [Driving Query Pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders). Unfortunately, if you use this pattern, you will indeed have as many queries to your secondary repository (for items details, `subDivisions` in your case) as items returned by your reader. However, I don't see how you can avoid this to solve your problem.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine - Thank you for the answer. It looks to me this is very common use case in integrated system where you may need data based on some parameter from other systems. Can I assumed now its impossible to implement in Spring Batch ?

Comment: No, don't assume that, because it is possible and you did it! I'm just saying that this pattern suffers from the well known [n + 1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping) and you probably need to tackle your requirement differently.